# Compare Swift enum regardless of the associated value

Tags: swift, enums, swift2

Is it somehow possible to test an enum case regardless of the associated value ?

```
enum Abc {
    case A(a:Int)
    case B(b:Int)
}

let a = Abc.A(a:1)

a == Abc.A  // <= Not possible
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can do this in a `switch`:

```
switch a {
case .A:
    print("it's A")
default:
    print("it's not A")
}
```

Or use pattern matching in an `if` statement:

```
if case .A = a {
    print("it's A")
} else {
    print("it's not A")
}
```

If you're still interested in the associated value after matching the case, you can extract it like so:

```
switch a {
case .A(let value):
    ...
}
```

```
if case .A(let value) = a {
    ...
}
```

Note [@overactor's comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808161/compare-swift-enum-regardless-of-the-associated-value#comment63081575_37808397) that you can also write this as `case let .A(value)` – it's mainly a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Does `if case` support somehow also cases where `a` is an optional `ABC?`

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Sure, you just add a question mark after the pattern to match against optionals, e.g `if case .A(let value)? = a` or `if case .A? = a`

Comment: Since you're going for quite an exhaustive answer, might want to add that the let can also be right after the case and that you can match against enums containing a particular value. i.e. `if case .A(a:1)`

Comment: @overactor Both good points, although matching against a particular associated value is exactly what OP doesn't want to do, thus I'm not sure it's worth adding to the answer ;) Although I have edited my answer to include your comment about the alternative syntax for binding the associated value, thanks for raising that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `if case`

```
enum ABC {
    case A(a: Int)
    case B(b: Int)
}

let a = ABC.A(a: 1)

if case .A = a {
    ...
}
```